# How to detect pattern in an image using OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have following frame from my video stream. It is a binary mask image generated after applying threshold to original grayscale image.

[image]

In the center of the image, we can see 4 dots. I want to find out centroid of each of these 4 dots. Other considerations are as under:
4 dots will be in a formation of a rhombus or quadrilateral. Their orientation can be any direction. Their scaling can be different in different frames as camera moves near or away from these dots. Also, not necessarily, they would be enclosed by a black rhombus region, as shown in figure above. Shape of this black region within which we have to detect 4 dots can be arbitrary.

We want to detect these deterministically using OpenCV functions (No CNN).

We have already tried things like erosion, dilation. But, the solution is not able to deterministically identify 4 dots with lots of white pixels all around as shown in figure above.

Kindly guide. Thanks in advance.

Comment: source data required. no screenshots, no filtering. people always think their filtering doesn't harm the situation.